# How can I install an intellij plugin from source?

Tags: java, plugins, ant, intellij-idea, ideavim

I'm trying to install the [ideaVim](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164) plugin for intellij from source.  I'm using this [repo](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/tree/0.35).

When I `cd` into the top level of the ideavim directory and then run `ant jar`, it produces the `IdeaVim.jar` file fine.

Then I go into my `~/.IntelliJIdea13/config/` folder and do a mkdir plugins to create the directory.  I then copied my `IdeaVim.jar` file into this folder.  So then I start intellij and go to plugins and enable the ideaVim plugin and it tells me to restart intellij.  So I do but when it starts up I get this error:

```
Plugin 'IdeaVIM' failed to initialize and will be disabled.  Please restart Intellij IDEA.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.maddyhome.idea.vim.VimPlugin PluginClassLoader[IdeaVIM, 0.35]
  at com.intellij.idea.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:68)
  ...
```

Does anyone have any idea why this could be failing to initialize?  Did I do the ant build wrong or do I have to include more then my `.jar` file in `~/.IntelliJIdea13/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building the plugin from source is unlikely to be the issue. The issue is probably how you added the plugin to IntelliJ.

Try adding the plugin through IntelliJ's GUI (version 13.1.3):

1. `Preferences > Plugins > Install plugin from disk...`
2. Navigate to the `.jar` file

[image]